# QueryOver - How to select only one object from a join of three tables

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Assuming that I have objects similar to this:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public IList<UsersRentingLog> UsersRentLog { get; set; }
}

public class Car 
{
    public int CarId { get; set; } 
    public IList<UsersRentingLog> CarRentLog { get; set; }
}

public class UsersRentingLog
{
    public Userid { get; set; }
    public CarId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to select all users who rented a particular car..

The sql for this would simply be

```
select c.*
from [User] u
    inner join UsersRentingLog l on u.userid = l.UserId
    inner join Car c on l.CarId = c.CarId
where u.userid = @UserId
```

I am trying to get this query to work in QueryOver, NHibernate, and so far, I have got this:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = QueryOver.of<User>()
    .where(r => r.UserId == userId)
    .JoinQueryOver<UsersRentingLog>(l => l.UsersRentLog)
    .JoinQueryOver<Car>(c => c.Car)
    .DetachedCriteria
    ;
```

This is selecting, as expected, every single property from all three joined tables, but I actually want to select only Cars. 
How can I do this please?

---

**Update on correct answer**

So, after the answer, I had to make few modifications (mostly minor syntax errors) and thought I'd post the working version.

Because my user doesn't have a direct reference to the car, I had to modify the alias to go with this

```
UsersRentingLog logAlias = null; 
var subQuery = QueryOver.of<User>()
    .Where(user => user.UserId == userId)
    .JoinAlias(user => user.UsersRentLog, () => logAlias)
    .subQuery.Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property(() => logAlias.Car.Id)));


var query = _session.QueryOver<Car>();
    query.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(car => car.Id).In(subQuery)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List<Car>();
```

The above bit, I am using detached criteria, so I rewrote the second code block like so:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = QueryOver.Of<Car>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(car => car.Id).In(subQuery)
    .TransformUsing(new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
    .DetachedCriteria
    ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Car carAlias = null;
var subQuery = QueryOver.of<User>()
    .Where(user => user.UserId == userId)
    .JoinAlias(user => user.Cars, () => carAlias)
    subQuery.Select(Projections.Distinct(
      Projections.Property(() => carAlias.Id)));

var query = _session.QueryOver<Car>();
query.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(car => car.Id).In(subQuery);
.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
.List<Car>();
```

Comment: Hi, I had to make a few modifications, but it definitely opened the right doors for me, thanks.

Comment: This sadly generates some pretty crummy sql and isn't the same as the OP's original raw query. You won't be able to do an order by clause in the subQuery like you would if you could just do a simple join.